# Network Configuration for Auto Scale in SL

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

When I add a group with options, how can I set the Network Component for "Balance Across Multiple VLANs" and "Preserve Balance Across VLANs On Downscale". I can't find a configuration field of a network component.
[image: adding group with option]

Answer (score 0):

Well the first option: **Balance Across Multiple VLANs**. If you enabled this option through [Control Portal](https://control.softlayer.com/), it will load the purchased vlans. So this is not a flag. We can simulate this feature through API but it depends of many factors. I will try to build a script for this, I will let you know any news about it.

Regarding to **Preserve Balance Across VLANs On Downscale**, this is the **balancedTerminationFlag**, you should set this property in your code like:

> templateObject.setBalancedTerminationFlag(true);
>
> **Updated**

```
package com.softlayer.api.ScaleGroup;

import com.softlayer.api.ApiClient;
import com.softlayer.api.RestApiClient;
import com.softlayer.api.service.Account;
import com.softlayer.api.service.Location;
import com.softlayer.api.service.network.Vlan;
import com.softlayer.api.service.scale.Group;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * This script Get Vlans as Control Portal does
 *
 * Important Manual Pages:
 * http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getNetworkVlans
 *
 * @license <http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/License>
 * @authon SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. <sldn@softlayer.com>
 * @version 0.2.2 (master branch)
 */
public class GetVlans {

    List<Vlan> publicVlans = new ArrayList<Vlan>();
    List<Vlan> privateVlans = new ArrayList<Vlan>();
    public GetVlans()
    {
        // Define your SoftLayer's username and apiKey
        String username = "set me";
        String apiKey = "set me";

        /**
         * Define Region as Control Portal and datacenter name
         * e.g. for datacenter: dal05, dal06, dal09, lon02 or First Available (This option get all vlans from datacenter from the region)
         */
        String region = "na-usa-central-1";
        String datacenter = "First Available";

        // Set privateNetworkOnly and preserverBalanceAcrossVLANsOnDownscale flags
        boolean privateNetworkOnly = false;
        boolean preserverBalanceAcrossVLANsOnDownscale = false;

        // Create client and services
        ApiClient client = new RestApiClient().withCredentials(username, apiKey);
        Account.Service accountService = Account.service(client);
        Group.Service groupService = Group.service(client);
        com.softlayer.api.service.location.Group.Service locationService;

        // Define Object Masks to get additional properties
        accountService.withMask().networkVlans().subnets();
        accountService.withMask().networkVlans().billingItem();
        accountService.withMask().networkVlans().networkSpace();
        accountService.withMask().networkVlans().primaryRouter();
        accountService.withMask().networkVlans().primaryRouter().datacenter();
        accountService.withMask().networkVlans().primaryRouter().datacenter().groups();
        accountService.withMask().networkVlans().localDiskStorageCapabilityFlag();
        accountService.withMask().networkVlans().sanStorageCapabilityFlag();

        // Define init parameter for locationService
        locationService = com.softlayer.api.service.location.Group.service(client, getRegionalGroupId(groupService, region));

        try {
            /**
             * Getting Vlans
             */
            if(datacenter == "First Available")
            {
                for(Location location : locationService.getLocations())
                {
                    getVlans(accountService, groupService, region, preserverBalanceAcrossVLANsOnDownscale, location.getName());
                    printVlans(privateNetworkOnly);
                }
            }else{
                getVlans(accountService, groupService, region, preserverBalanceAcrossVLANsOnDownscale, datacenter);
                printVlans(privateNetworkOnly);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves rion identifier
     * @param region string
     * @return region identifier
     */
    public Long getRegionalGroupId(Group.Service groupService, String region)
    {
        Long regionId = new Long(0);
        for(com.softlayer.api.service.location.Group regionalGroup : groupService.getAvailableRegionalGroups())
        {
            if(regionalGroup.getName().equals(region))
            {
                regionId = regionalGroup.getId();
            }
        }
        return regionId;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param accountService Account Service
     * @param groupService Group Service
     * @param region Define the region for the vlans
     * @param preserverBalanceAcrossVLANsOnDownscale Flag to get own vlans
     * @param location The location to get vlans
     */
    public void getVlans(Account.Service accountService, Group.Service groupService, String region, boolean preserverBalanceAcrossVLANsOnDownscale, String location)
    {
        publicVlans = new ArrayList<Vlan>();
        privateVlans = new ArrayList<Vlan>();
        System.out.println("Datacenter: " + location);
        for(Vlan vlan : accountService.getObject().getNetworkVlans()) {
            if (vlan.getPrimaryRouter().getDatacenter().getName().equals(location)) {
                for (com.softlayer.api.service.location.Group group : vlan.getPrimaryRouter().getDatacenter().getGroups()) {
                    if (group.getId() == getRegionalGroupId(groupService, region)) {

                        if (vlan.getNetworkSpace().equals("PUBLIC")) {
                            if (preserverBalanceAcrossVLANsOnDownscale) {
                                if (vlan.getBillingItem() != null) {
                                    publicVlans.add(vlan);
                                }
                            } else {
                                publicVlans.add(vlan);
                            }
                        } else {
                            if (vlan.getBillingItem() != null) {
                                privateVlans.add(vlan);
                            } else {
                                privateVlans.add(vlan);

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Print Vlans
     * @param privateNetworkOnly PrivateNetworkOnly flag, to get only private vlans
     */
    public void printVlans(boolean privateNetworkOnly)
    {
        if(!privateNetworkOnly)
        {
            System.out.println("PUBLIC");
            for(Vlan vlan : publicVlans)
            {
                System.out.println("Id: " + vlan.getId() + "     Vlan Number: " + vlan.getVlanNumber() + "         Router: " + vlan.getPrimaryRouter().getHostname() +
                        "   SAN: " + vlan.getSanStorageCapabilityFlag() + "  LOCAL: " + vlan.getLocalDiskStorageCapabilityFlag());
            }
        }
        System.out.println("PRIVATE");
        for(Vlan vlan : privateVlans)
        {
            System.out.println("Id: " + vlan.getId() + "     Vlan Number: " + vlan.getVlanNumber() + "         Router: " + vlan.getPrimaryRouter().getHostname() +
                    "    SAN: " + vlan.getSanStorageCapabilityFlag() + "   LOCAL: " + vlan.getLocalDiskStorageCapabilityFlag());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String []args)
    {
        new GetVlans();
    }
}
```

I attached a java script to get Vlans as Control Portal does, because I think that you are trying to automate Scale Groups. I hope it helps.

Comment: I attached a script to get vlans